# Convert packed bits to two's compliment int in Go

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

I have a 38 bit two's complement integer packed inside a byte slice. How do I extract this value correctly? If I simply pull out the 38 bits into an int64, it's not correct for negative numbers (because the left 28 bits are always all 0).

Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/BRvrihYAJ80

Bytes 4 to 8 make up 40 bits, I ignore the first two bits in byte 4 and then or+shift the rest into an int64. This works for positive numbers, but not negative. The binary is correct and when interpreted as an int38 come out (correctly) as -40520517670 - but when interpretted incorrectly as an int64 comes out as 234357389274.

How can I take these 38 bits and convert them to a 64 bit int correctly?

Comment: You have to subtract resulting value from maximal value of int38

Comment: Thanks very much - `x - 274877906944` gives -40520517670.